# Sending a mail with contact form in joomla

Tags: joomla

Im getting an error

`The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.`
When Im trying to send mail in joomla using inbuilt contact form

Answer (score 0):

Open your template's `index.php` file, and add the following line to its very beginning:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10000);
```

Please post back here if it doesn't work for you.